# How to copy a MultipartFile in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

In my method I have a **MultipartFile** (instance of StreamingMultipartFile) (`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`) passed as an argument.

Inside this method I need to get a copy of the file, as its InputStream is to be read by another method and the file is to be passed itself after that. I tried to reset the InputStream of the file but it doesn't work.

Also I tried to use GSON library and SerializationUtils methods from `org.springframework.util` package to serialize/deserialize but it doesn't succeeded as the class doesn't have no-args constructor.

So how the copy of such file can be obtained at all?

Answer (score 0):

I have found next solution - create custom class with next fields:

```
private final byte[] fileContent;
private final String fileName;
```

Also the class should implement the `MultipartFile` interface and override [all methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) based on specified fields accordingly.